# DataBindings lost during App-Switching/Tombstoning in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, data-binding, tombstoning, fast-app-switching

I've set up a viewmodel to bind a listcontrol to an ObservableCollection in my program. A UI control on the page adds and deletes objects to the collection, which works fine as the list is automatically updated.

After App-Switching and returning to the app, the buttons adds the objects, but the bindings seem to be lost. Any idea how I can maintain this even after returning? I don't really see the need to rebind the object (after defining it in XAML). Is there any way to foolproof this pattern, and ensure the bindings aren't lost upon returning to the app?

The XAML looks like this, but it's inside a UserControl - forgot to mention that

```
ItemsControl x:Name="PartyCollection" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PartyCollectiontemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding RoomParty, Source={StaticResource FormControlVM}}"
```

the codebehind looks like this

```
public class FormControlVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public ObservableCollection<Party> RoomParty
    {
        get
        {
            return App.appData.currentChoices.roomParty;
        }
        set
        {
            App.appData.currentChoices.roomParty = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("RoomParty"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a simple repro? (There are lots of ways you could be doing what you describe.)

Comment: I'm surprised that it doesn't handle it internally. do you thin I should rebind the values?

Comment: I just found out that it might be because I'm serializing/deserializing App.appData.CurrentChoices , and i'm not sure if ObservableCollection is serializable. any advice?

Comment: It also looks like I should use CollectionChanged instead of PropertyChanged, but i'm not finding much help online.